Gamma regression with XGBoost
I'll try to be brief. I have two questions about what exactly happens when I train a gradient boosted ensemble of trees using, say, XGBoost in order to perform a Gamma regression. I apologize in advance for any (very) likely misunderstanding from my part - but I do appreciate any further clarification very much!
Suppose we have $n-1$ learners which as an ensemble estimate the target $y(x)$ with $\hat{y}^{(n-1)}(x)$. The goal would be to add another learner, say $f^{(n)}$, and my updated estimation $\hat{y}^{(n)}(x)$ for $y(x)$ is given by $$\hat{y}^{(t-1)}(x)+f^{(n)}(x)$$ We then choose the structure of the learner $f^{(n)}$ in such a way that an objective function $$\sum L(y(x), \hat{y}^{(n)}(x)) + \omega(f^{(n)})$$ is minimized. Let's ignore $\omega$ for the time being. I am assuming that if I set the parameter objective to reg:gamma then I'm trying to maximize the negative likelihood function of a Gamma distribution. The two questions are quite basic :

How are the scale and shape parameters taken in account ? The expression for the ML of a Gamma distribution is in terms of one of those parameters but there is no (explicit) way to make XGBoost aware of this ?
Related with the first question : are we implicitly assuming that the residuals are also Gamma distributed ? What I have in mind is the following : consider a regression task where the target variable is obviously following something that resembles a Gamma distribution upon visual inspection. However, the moment I add more than a learner, I am no longer dealing with the original target but rather a residual. Are we still considering it to be Gamma distributed?


The answers and comments at Loss function in for gamma objective function in regression in XGBoost? suggest that the scale parameter is just assumed to be 1.  The model prediction is the mean of the distribution.
The trees (even the first!) are trained toward the pseudoresiduals of the loss function, which in gamma regression will be different than for another loss function; that's where the objective comes into play.  Only the output random variable is assumed to be gamma-distributed, not the (pseudo)residuals.
